# Nested Grid programmatically WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, nested

As of now I'm able to create a datagrid programmatically using Datagrid class and then programmatically keep on adding rows and columns.
Now how do I add inner datagrid to a particular row of outer grid programmatically?

Comment: `any suggestions ?` - Yes, learn MVVM before you ever write a single line of code in WPF.

Comment: Cant i use dataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate() to add an inner datagrid into an outer datagrid ?